# Не работает MySQL на Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

У меня возникли проблемы при подключении к MySQL. Выдает следующую ошибку:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Пробовал исправить, как на [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXjJRrbKjp0)

Но когда делаю `restart mysql` выдает следующее:

> [....] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Полное удаление и новая установка mysql не помагает.

ОС Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Как можно исправить?

Comment: mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Вск 2017-12-10 19:32: EET
  Process: 4138 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit
Дек 10 19:32: admin1-H81M-S2V systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time
Дек 10 19:32: admin1-H81M-S2V systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Дек 10 19:32:34 admin1-H81M-S2V systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeate
Дек 10 19:32:34 admin1-H81M-S2V systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Serv

Comment: Вот посмотрите здесь на английском. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: *"Полное удаление"* -- что под этим понимается?

Comment: использовал вот это:      apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
 apt-get --purge remove mysql-client
 apt-get --purge remove mysql-common
apt-get autoremove
 apt-get autoclean
 rm -rf /etc/mysql
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client phpmyadmin

Comment: нашел решение проблемы: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server

Comment: Для начала почитать /var/log/mysql/error.log